# Upload the Laravel Project to the Server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

whats wrong when i  Upload the Laravel Project to the Server , tell me like this
i work in 000webhost to Upload to the Server

I tried to check the database information, but all are correct and the website made but i can't
register or login somethink is wrong

Comment: How can we help with this absolutely vague description of nothing? You need to narrow down what the issue is and explain it better, else this question is not understandable at all and lacks lots of info...

Answer (score 1):

You gave very vague info so it's hard to diagnose. Anyway, you can try these:

**1. Check the DNS**

Point your domain to the host's IP address. On your host, create a very simple file like index.html in */public_html* directory, then try to access it via your browser. If you see the content, it's ok.

**2. Try to access Laravel**

Zip your project with the *vendor*, then upload it to the host. By default, 000webhost finds the *index.php* in */public_html* directory, so this is the trick:

- Put files in *yourproject/public* in */public_html* directory
- Put the remains in the root directory
- Don't forget to set up the database and *.env* file, you can upload it or clone from *.env.example*.

Try to access via your browser again, if you can see anything from Laravel (including errors), it's ok.

**3. Diagnose from Laravel error page and log**

If you see *Access denied for user...* or *Unknown database...*, check the connection info in *.env*. If you see migration or query errors, try to import from your local database to diagnose.

If you can access the home page but can't access the other routes, check */public_html/.htaccess*. Files beginning with a dot are often hidden in some file managers, so you may lose them somewhere.

If you can't access file storage (for public images, etc.), run *php artisan storage:link* or create a symlink manually from */storage/app/public* to */public_html/storage*.